# phpMyAdmin pmahomme theme changing/removing white text outline?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

The new phpMyAdmin update that uses the pmahomme theme has a white drop shadow/sunken in white border around the text. its a bit to much text decoration when you're reading through a large database.

Does anyone know how to change this to a solid text with no decoration?

Comment: Sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this line: `text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;` in the theme_right.css.php file.